# Consulta INNER JOIN en Android con SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, join

Necesito hacer una consulta `select` con dos bases de datos diferentes. ¿Cómo podría?

De la base de datos `Xtraining` tengo la tabla `dbo.tbUsuarioOperario` con el campo `idOperario`.

De la base de datos `Workflow` tengo la tabla `dbo.llamadas` con los campos `fecha`, `mensaje`, `de`, `estado` y `IdUsuarioDestino`.

Answer (score 3):

Es la misma sintaxis que la consulta de dos tablas de una misma base de datos. Primero [aquí](http://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Consultas-SELECT-multi-tabla-Tipos-de-JOIN.aspx) te dejo un poco de información sobre los `JOIN`s. Ahora bien, imagínate que tienes las bases de datos `baseDatos1` y `baseDatos2`, ambas con su esquema `dbo`. Ahora en la primera hay una tabla `tblbd1` y en la segunda hay una tabla que se llama `tblbd2`. Supongamos que las dos tablas están en los [esquemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd207005.aspx) `dbo` de sus respectivas bases de datos. El query sería como sigue:

```
SELECT * FROM baseDatos1.dbo.tblbd1
INNER JOIN baseDatos2.dbo.tblbd2 
ON baseDatos1.tblbd1.campo = baseDatos2.tblbd2.campo
```

Ahora si tienes más de una condición solo debes de agregar un `AND` después de la primera

```
SELECT * FROM baseDatos1.dbo.tblbd1
INNER JOIN baseDatos2.dbo.tblbd2 
ON baseDatos1.tblbd1.campo = baseDatos2.tblbd2.campo
AND baseDatos1.tblbd1.fecha = baseDatos2.tblbd2.fecha
AND baseDatos1.tblbd1.id_campo = baseDatos2.tblbd2.id_campo
```

Para seleccionar ciertos campos solo debes especificar el campo y de que tabla es que procede

```
SELECT t1.fecha, t2.id, t1.estatus FROM baseDatos1.dbo.tblbd1 t1
INNER JOIN baseDatos2.dbo.tblbd2 t2
ON t1.campo = t2.campo
```

Nota: En esta última consulta uso un [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) para que la consulta se simplifique